# MonoPrice Maker Select V2 Build Plate Movement issue

Tags: y-axis, monoprice-maker-select

I just recently changed out the OEM Build Plate adhesive pad with a PEI Sheet. Prior to doing this work, the build plate moved back and forth just fine along the Y Axis (front to back). The Build plate could be moved manually until it hit the front and back frame of the printer. The build plate also hit the Y Axis Endstop just fine.

After doing the work to replace the PEI plate....I turned on the printer and homed it and when it attempted to automatically slide the build plate back to the end stop it started shaking violently as the plate moved overtop of the end stop switch without touching it.

The plate also sails overtop of the front and back frames of the printer. I have no idea what happened. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to 3dPrinting.SE!

Comment: Can you add some pictures of your build plate at the front and back of the rails as well as the y end stop?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GbKPdC_cXnI This is exactly what my printer does. When moving the plate manually, it doesn't touch the metal trigger on the end stop. The description on the video seemed to suggest the metal trigger was bent, but mine looks just like it did when I put the thing together.

Comment: FIXED: Simply unplugging the machine for a few minutes cleared out whatever was causing the issue.